# How do I use a button to execute a function that involves images

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Im working on a project with slot machines and im trying to make a payout rates screen, where it will show you all of the images you can roll and how much they increase your bet. To do this i have this function and the button shown below

```
def show_info():
    odds = Tk()
    odds.title("Odds")
    fresh_monky_img_odds = Image.open("freshmonky.gif")
    fresh_monky_img_odds = fresh_monky_img_odds.resize((75, 75))
    fresh_monky_img_odds = ImageTk.PhotoImage(fresh_monky_img_odds)
    test_btn = Button(odds, image = fresh_monky_img_odds, width = 40, height = 40)
    test_btn.pack()
    odds.geometry("300x300")
    odds.mainloop()
odds_btn = Button(slots, height = 2, width = 30, text = "Odds", command = show_info)
odds_btn.pack()
```

The function itself works because I tested it by calling the function without a button and it worked fine, but with a button it doesnt work

The error I get is:
`_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage10" doesn't exist`

Comment: It is because you have multiple instances of `Tk`.  Use `Toplevel` in the function.  Also using local variable to hold the image will make the image not be shown because it will be destroyed upon completion of the function.

Comment: where would i put Toplevel in the function, do i replace Tk with toplevel?

Comment: Yes and remove calling `mainloop()` inside the function.

Comment: I replaced Tk with toplevel and it worked, thanks a lot man

Comment: look out for [bug in PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

Answer (score -1):

You can use Tk() only 1 time for creating screen. So for creating a new screen use can't use Tk() again. So you can use Toplevel() for creating new screen. check correction in code.

```
> def show_info():
    odds = Toplevel(root)  #instead of root your main screen name
    odds.title("Odds")
    fresh_monky_img_odds = Image.open("freshmonky.gif")
    fresh_monky_img_odds = fresh_monky_img_odds.resize((75, 75))
    fresh_monky_img_odds = ImageTk.PhotoImage(fresh_monky_img_odds)
    test_btn = Button(odds, image = fresh_monky_img_odds, width = 40, height = 40)
    test_btn.pack()
    odds.geometry("300x300")
    odds.mainloop()
odds_btn = Button(slots, height = 2, width = 30, text = "Odds", command = show_info)
odds_btn.pack()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use multiple Tk() windows but if you do that, when creating photoimages, you need to specify in wich window you will use them so if you replace this line

```
fresh_monky_img_odds = ImageTk.PhotoImage(fresh_monky_img_odds)
```

by this line

```
fresh_monky_img_odds = ImageTk.PhotoImage(master=odds ,image fresh_monky_img_odds)
```

if id didn't work either, keep a reference of your image in a global variable.
the following script should work:

```
fresh_monky_img_odds = "none"
def show_info():
    global fresh_monky_img_odds
    odds = Tk()
    odds.title("Odds")
    fresh_monky_img_odds = Image.open("freshmonky.gif")
    fresh_monky_img_odds = fresh_monky_img_odds.resize((75, 75))
    fresh_monky_img_odds = ImageTk.PhotoImage(master=odds ,image fresh_monky_img_odds)
    test_btn = Button(odds, image = fresh_monky_img_odds, width = 40, height = 40)
    test_btn.pack()
    odds.geometry("300x300")
    odds.mainloop()
odds_btn = Button(slots, height = 2, width = 30, text = "Odds", command = show_info)
odds_btn.pack()
```